# How to configure GCP Cloud Tasks Queue for very slow dispatch due to 3rd party SLA downstream?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, queue, rate-limiting, google-cloud-tasks

I need to set up a Cloud Tasks queue that sends HTTP requests to a 3rd party API. The external API can only accept a few requests per minute and I would like to set up rate limiting on the Cloud Tasks so that tasks flow at a very slow pace: no more than 1 request every 15 seconds.

From the docs, I can see that:

When you use any Cloud Tasks API method, you have two fields to define the queue dispatch rate:

max_dispatches_per_second
max_concurrent_dispatches

I have set both of those parameters to 1. My questions are:

How can I achieve my goal of 1 request per 15 seconds using these parameters?
Can I set max_dispatches_per_second to something like 0.10?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You can set the rate to be the number of requests per minute but I am not sure if **4/m** means one per 15 seconds or 4 in a row and then wait for a minute to elapse. I recommend that you test and then update your question. More details: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#ratelimits and  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref#rate

Comment: Seems I have to use queue.yaml approach instead of the SDK approach for setting up the Cloud Tasks.

Comment: @JohnHanley - as recommended, tested and updated the question with the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Through the gcloud SDK, you can configure the `max_dispatches_per_second` property to be decimals. This achieves something similar to `rate` property you are able to set on the `queue.yaml`. **It is advised not to combine these two approaches: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/queue-yaml#additional_information_about_cloud_tasks_queue_management_methods**.

**Example**:
`--max-dispatches-per-second=0.016666667` sets the queue for dispatching once every minute.